# Centroid of the segmented object not in the center

Tags: 3d, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I segment the object from the point cloud in PCL and have the point cloud of the object. I calculate the centroid of the segmented object in this manner using the PCL methods:

pcl::PointXYZRGB centroidDS;
            pcl::computeCentroid(*cleaned, centroidDS);

When I visualize the centroid with overlay to the object it is always located to the edges of the object. I use centroid as a feature so would be nice if someone has an idea how to calculate this. centroid of a segmented object should be more or less at the center of the object.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you don't have multiple identical points somewhere? That would pull the centroid away from what appears to be the logical center of the point cloud. If you think the pcl function does something wrong just test it by

```
float x = y = z = 0.0;
for (int i = 0; i < cleaned->points.size(); i++){
    x += cleaned->points[i].x;
    y += cleaned->points[i].y;
    z += cleaned->points[i].z;
}
x = x / cleaned->points.size();
y = y / cleaned->points.size();
z = z / cleaned->points.size();
```

this should be the same as the centroid.
If this is your problem you could try removing the multiple points or perhaps doing a voxel grid filtering of the point cloud so you'll get a uniformly distributed cloud. 
http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/voxel_grid.php

Comment: I have done voxel grid downsampling prior to segmentation. How do I check for the multiple points. Can it be that my segmentation is not good enough and there is some small points or blob that I don't see that make the centroid to be shifted.

Comment: If you have done the voxel grid downsampling there should not be any multiple points or a cluster of points in a small area. Obviously depending on your grid size. Might want to check that too.  However if you still have duplicates or quasi duplicates where the coordinate difference is minimal I think you could use octree to calculate how many points fall into a  voxel. Also just a normal kdtree search with a radius and count the number of neighbors within a distance works. This post talks about octree. http://www.pcl-users.org/Saving-Octree-voxel-density-information-to-file-td3840729.html